# Can't log into private registry between instances on Play-with-docker

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am very new to docker so please bear with me. I am following the documentation on https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#running-a-domain-registry

I have spin up 2 nodes on play-with-docker.com for my learning.

On Node1 I am able to set up a private registry successfully using the following command

```
docker run -d \
  -p 5000:5000 \
  --restart=always \
  --name registry \
  -v "$(pwd)"/auth:/auth \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
  -v "$(pwd)"/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  registry:2
```

I was also able to pull and push images from Node1 to the registry. However, when I go on Node2 and try to log in to the registry it gives the following error:

```
[node2] (local) root@192.168.0.7 ~
$ docker login 192.168.0.8:5000
Username: testuser
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.0.8:5000/v2/: dial tcp 192.168.0.8:5000: connect: connection refused
```

please let me know what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Node2 can't access port 5000 on 192.168.0.8. This looks like a network issue.

Are your nodes in the same network?
Are there firewall rules that might be blocking access to port 5000?
Are you sure 192.168.0.8 is the correct IP address of your Node1 machine?

To test your TCP connection use `telnet`. For example `telnet 192.168.0.8 5000` (assuming 192.168.0.8 is the correct IP address).

Comment: This is what i get 
````
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.18 ~
$ curl 192.168.0.17:5000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.17 port 5000: Connection refused
````

but these 2 nodes are definitely on the same network, cos i was able to create a swap out of these 2

Comment: I might have found the issue, dont know why tho. It seems like when i run the command `docker run -d \
  -p 5000:5000 \
  --restart=always \
  --name registry \
  -v "$(pwd)"/auth:/auth \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
  -v "$(pwd)"/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  registry:2` it doesnt open up the port 5000

Comment: If it doesn't open port 5000 that means that the container does not start properly. Are you sure the container is UP once you run the command? Use `docker ps` to check that. Also `ss -tulpn` command will show you the ports that are being listened to (5000 should be there, once you start up the registry container).

Comment: think i figured out the issue. The port wont open if the TLS cert arent setup, but some how it still work in local, just outside wont be able to connect